# how to access serialized data in django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have this data in my serializer

```
EditScheduleSerializerByDate(data={'time1': '09:00:00', 't1course1': 'Machine Learning'}, initial={'ss': <QuerySet [<Schedule: 2021-02-27 13:00:00 Machine Learning >, <Schedule: 2021-02-27 13:00:00 Deep Learning >, <Schedule: 2021-02-27 14:00:00 Deep Learning >]>})
```

I am unable to access data using `serializer.data` but I am able to access `serializer.initial`

It is giving empty list in `serializer.data`

Answer (score 3):

You should call `.is_valid()` method before accessing `serializer.data`:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    # Now you can get serializer.data
```

Or you can call `initial_data` to access data before calling `is_valid()` method:

```
print(serializer.initial_data)
```